# Java: How to save an input choice in a text file

Tags: java, filewriter

The user is presented with a list of strings. The program will ask the user to input the number that corresponds to the string they wish to delete from a text file (in this case, the .m3u file). How would i permanently save the change the user has made to the text file?

My code:

```
else if (userSelectedCode == OptionID.OPTION_DELETE_MUSIC_TRACK) {
        String filename = "user needs to select this.m3u";
        //model.DeleteFirstPlaylist(filename);
        List<M3UTrack> trackList = model.getFirstPlaylist().getTracks();
        for (int i = 0; i < trackList.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println((i+1) + ": " + trackList.get(i).getTrackFilename());
        }
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number of the music track to delete");
        int trackNum = in.nextInt();
        {
            model.getFirstPlaylist().deleteTrack(trackList.get(trackNum-1));
        }
```

I suspect it involves the use of FileWriter? Would this be a start?:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:/Data/Projects/MusicOrganizer/music.m3u");    
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
```

Comment: well... if you know how to format the *contents* of the file, the writing is easy... although for binary files you'd be better of with a FileOutputStream

Comment: If you share the code you use to *read* that m3u file?